# Why does VIProductVersion argument override value of ProductVersion key?

Tags: nsis

Code snippet from the nsi script:

```
VIProductVersion 1.2.0.0   
VIAddVersionKey /LANG=${LANG_ENGLISH} FileVersion 1.1.0.0
```

I want to set *FileVersion* to `1.1.0.0` but in file properties it is set to `1.2.0.0`. I also noticed that `VIProductVersion` executed on its own adds *FileVersion* key and sets its value.

Documentation says that [VIProductVersion](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.8.3.2) adds the *Product Version* but what I see is that *FileVersion* is actually added. Is this the bug in NSIS? What is the purpose of `VIAddVersionKey FileVersion` if value it sets is overriden with one set by `VIProductVersion`?

`VIAddVersionKey` requires `VIProductVersion` call, script does not compile otherwise.

Versions I am using: EclipseNSIS 0.9.8; MakeNSIS 2.46. OS: Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version info resource is stored in two parts:

- [VS_FIXEDFILEINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646997%28VS.85%29.aspx) is a fixed block with product and file versions, VIProductVersion sets this
- Zero, one or more (multiple languages) string blocks with one or more name=value strings, VIAddVersionKey sets those.

Some applications use the FileVersion string and fall back to VS_FIXEDFILEINFO::dwFileVersion if the string is not present, other apps only use VS_FIXEDFILEINFO::dwFileVersion etc.

`VIProductVersion "1.2.3.4"` will generate a version header that looks like

```
1 VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION 1,2,3,4
PRODUCTVERSION 1,2,3,4
FILEOS 0x4
FILETYPE 0x1
```

this is often enough but it will not let you set PRODUCTVERSION != FILEVERSION.

I would consider this a bug in NSIS, they should add a VIFileVersion command or extend VIProductVersion to `VIProductVersion <productver> [filever]`.

You can add a feature request on the [tracker](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?atid=373088&group_id=22049&func=browse).

<strike>In the mean time you might be able to work around this by calling [resource hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) during the build with !packhdr</strike>

---

Edit:

It can be done with 2.46 at compile time with !packhdr, external 3rd party tools (I was unable to get reshacker to import a .rc version resource so I had to convert to .res first) and horrible hacks:

```
!macro HackyVIFileVersion reshack gorcjorg fixedfilever
;http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/
;http://web.archive.org/web/20090918063311/http://www.jorgon.freeserve.co.uk/Gorcjorg.zip
!searchreplace HackyVIFileVersion_id "${__TIME__}" ":" ""
!define HackyVIFileVersion_cmd "$%TEMP%\nsisVIFV${HackyVIFileVersion_id}.cmd"
!appendfile "${HackyVIFileVersion_cmd}" `@echo off&setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION$\n`
!appendfile "${HackyVIFileVersion_cmd}" `set eh=%TEMP%\exehead%~1.tmp$\n`
!appendfile "${HackyVIFileVersion_cmd}" `set rh=%~2$\n`
!appendfile "${HackyVIFileVersion_cmd}" `call "%rh%" -extract "%eh%", "%eh%1.rc", VersionInfo,1,$\n`
!appendfile "${HackyVIFileVersion_cmd}" `> "%eh%2.rc" echo.LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US $\n` ;must force lang for Gorcjorg
!appendfile "${HackyVIFileVersion_cmd}" `FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%A IN ("%eh%1.rc") DO ($\n`
!appendfile "${HackyVIFileVersion_cmd}" `   FOR /F "usebackq" %%B IN ('%%A') DO ($\n`
!appendfile "${HackyVIFileVersion_cmd}" `       if "%%~B"=="FILEVERSION" (>> "%eh%2.rc" echo.FILEVERSION %~4) else (>> "%eh%2.rc" echo.%%A)$\n`
!appendfile "${HackyVIFileVersion_cmd}" `   )$\n`
!appendfile "${HackyVIFileVersion_cmd}" `)$\n`
!appendfile "${HackyVIFileVersion_cmd}" `call "%~3" /fo "%eh%.res" /r "%eh%2.rc"$\n`
!appendfile "${HackyVIFileVersion_cmd}" `call "%rh%" -addoverwrite "%eh%", "%eh%", "%eh%.res", versioninfo,1,$\n`
!appendfile "${HackyVIFileVersion_cmd}" `del "%eh%2.rc"&del "%eh%1.rc"&del "%eh%.res"&del "%~0"`
!packhdr "$%TEMP%\exehead${HackyVIFileVersion_id}.tmp" '"${HackyVIFileVersion_cmd}" "${HackyVIFileVersion_id}" "${reshack}" "${gorcjorg}" "${fixedfilever}"'
!undef HackyVIFileVersion_cmd
!undef HackyVIFileVersion_id 
!macroend


VIProductVersion "1.2.3.4"
VIAddVersionKey /LANG=1033 FileVersion 5.6.7.8
VIAddVersionKey /LANG=1033 ProductVersion "1.2.3.4"
VIAddVersionKey /LANG=1033 Comments "A test comment"
!insertmacro HackyVIFileVersion "C:\tools\ResHacker.exe" "C:\tools\GoRC.exe" "5,6,7,8"
```

...and you end up with this version resource:

```
1 VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION 5,6,7,8
PRODUCTVERSION 1,2,3,4
FILEOS 0x4
FILETYPE 0x1
{
BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
{
    BLOCK "040904e4"
    {
        VALUE "Comments", "A test comment"
        VALUE "FileVersion", "5.6.7.8"
        VALUE "ProductVersion", "1.2.3.4"
    }
}

BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
{
    VALUE "Translation", 0x0409 0x04E4
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it really helped me to understand how `VIProductVersion` works. It should really be either extended as you suggested or, at least, a remark should be added about it to NSIS documentation.

Answer (score 4):

I thought I would mention the obvious workaround for this bug.

When using NSIS 2.46 set the *VIProductVersion* to your *FileVersion* then with *VIAddVersionKey* set the *ProductVersion*, you will also need to set *Fileversion* to avoid a NSIS compiler warning.

```
VIProductVersion ${INSTALLER_VERSION}
VIAddVersionKey ProductName ${PROGRAM_NAME}
VIAddVersionKey FileVersion ${INSTALLER_VERSION}
VIAddVersionKey ProductVersion ${PROGRAM_VERSION}
...
```